# Laravel NotFoundHttpException on API

Tags: php, laravel

I have API URL like:

```
http://example.com/api/driverAcceptOrder?id=bee74e39-ff38-46a6-9e5d-6db799d2be8c&driverId=3453a3a9-7f58-434a-8dab-95c3469e6238
```

method is `POST` and it takes 2 parameter `id` and `driverId`

When I try to run this URL in postman I get:

```
Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('driverAcceptOrder/{id}/{driverId}', 'Api\DriversController@driverAcceptOrder');
```

**Controller**

```
public function driverAcceptOrder(Request $request, $id, $driverId)
{
    $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
    $defs = OrderDefaultProgress::where('name', 'Driver OTW ke pelanggan')->first();
    $driver = Driver::where('id', $driverId)->with('user')->first();
    $order->update(['driver_id' => $driverId]);
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $driver,
        'message' => 'Pengemudi Dalam perjalanan menuju pelanggan.'
    ], 200);
}
```

**Note**

1. Route is not restricted by Auth middleware (its public)
2. I've added exception to my `VerifyCsrfToken` file as `protected $except = ['/api/*'];`

**Any idea?**

Comment: it looks like you dont have 'api' before 'driverAcceptOrder/{id}/{driverId}' in your route

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes that worked but where should I place them in postman in order to get such url? when I put them in params they show as my question url :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your url is wrong

`example.com/api/driverAcceptOrder?id=bee74e39-ff38-46a6-9e5d-6db799d2be8c&driverId=3453a3a9-7f58-434a-8dab-95c3469e6238`

here after `?`  all is query paramter which is used in **GET** method to send data

```php
Route::get('driverAcceptOrder',"..");
```

which is not found in your case that's why your getting

> NotFoundHttpException

for your case url should be

`example.com/api/driverAcceptOrder/bee74e39/3453a3a9-7f58-434a-8dab-95c3469e6238`

this will be handel by

```php
Route::post('driverAcceptOrder/{id}/{driverId}', 'Api\DriversController@driverAcceptOrder');
```

you can learn more about

**GET** and **POST** here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp